# new ext hard drive. how change from ROOT owner to me?

Tags: ownership

Installed new external hard drive.  Won't let me install data.  Ownership listed as ROOT.  How do I change ownership to ME? 
(Disk was reformatted from msdos/NTFS to GPT/ext4)

Comment: Please run `sudo lsblk -f` and add to your question

Comment: You have to mount your new partition first somewhere, for example on /home1 and set the permissions afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

First mount the hard disk. Then, open Terminal and type in:

```
sudo chown (your user name, e.g. gwen):(your username again) '/media/gwen/ExHDD'
```

*(NOTE: 1)By user name I mean the name you typed in the "User name" field with lower-case letters during installation. 2) The path '/media/gwen/ExHDD' is an example. For real external HDD ownership transfer, type in for the path '/media/(your user name)/(the external HDD's label'.)*

Type your password when it asks you, and you will have full ownership of your external hard disk.

Hope this works!

Comment: man chown https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown; maybe -R for recursivity.. if it's not empty

Comment: @user688056 "chown" changes file/folder ownership from root or another user, e.g. bajiru to your user (e.g. gwen) or another user (e.g. mark). It is not harmful at all. (if you think it is) I do not want to distribute harmful code before I even have tested it on my own Ubuntu PC. Plus, you did a great job searching for the command/code. You never know when someone will suggest you to try a harmful code e.g. "sudo rm / -r -f" which deletes everything  on the Linux system & on all mounted partitions. There are some trolls on the web suggesting newbies to try "deadly" comands. Be careful.

Comment: @user688056 Here is a link about some deadly Linux commands you should never run. https://www.howtogeek.com/125157/8-deadly-commands-you-should-never-run-on-linux/

Comment: your response was good, i was lazy and didn't argumented it ; my comment was made in the hope that OP will read the source (as in manual) or if the recursivity need arrives; thx for the link i liked the "~ to null" one :)

Comment: @user688056 You're welcome! :)

Comment: Bajiru's comment is what I was looking for.   No need to start confrontations.
My personal experience with CHOWN was on the root disk. Accessing another disk was what I lacked experience with. 
Thanks for everyones' input

Comment: @GwenWalcott You're welcome! Remember to accept my answer as the solution by clicking the tick (since it was the right answer) and adding "[SOLVED]" to the title.